# Cannot import custom npm package by package name

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm loosely following [this tutorial](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/angular/) to create my own angular npm package called `customlib` so I can manage dependencies across my projects without making them public on npm.

in my `app.module.ts` I get a `module not found: Can't resolve 'customlib'` error when I do the following:

```
import { customModule } from 'customlib';
```

it works fine if I do this though:

```
import { customModule } from '../../node_modules/customModule/dist-lib/index';
```

Is there something I'm missing? it's worth noting that I move all files I want to include in my package to the `dist-lib` directory.

My library's `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name" : "customlib",
    "version" : "0.1.0",
    "private" : true,
    "dependencies" : [
       ...
    ],
    "files" : [ "dist-lib/" ],
    "repository" : {
       "type" : "git",
       "url : "path/to/repo"
    },
    "types": "dist-lib/index.d.ts"
}
```

I'm adding the dependency in the consumer project's `package.json` as so:

```
"customlib" : "path/to/repo"
```

And I've also added the following to the consumer project's `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/customlib/dist-lib/index.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on consumer package.json dependencies:

```
"customlib" : "file:path/to/repo"
```

And not forget "npm install".

Answer (score 0):

I found a resource that was published by angular team that describes about creating a [angular package](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview#heading=h.k0mh3o8u5hx). And in here you can fin some examples as well as some packaging libraries.

- [generator-angular2-library](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)
- [ng-packagr](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr)

Please go through this document. Hope this helps.